# Phaser Game not rendering on normal page

Tags: phaser

I made a game with the Phaser game framework on a course, and now I want to add features and build upon that game.  The only problem is that I built the game with the course on webpack, which served the game on localhost:8080  I want to now stop using localhost and put the game on a normal website, but for that, I need to get it off localhost.  I think the problem is in the index.html file where I render the game.  Here is the index.html code:

```
<head>
 <style>
  body {
    padding: 200px;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/3.52.0/phaser.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/index.js"></script>
```

Please tell me how I can put my game on a normal website.  Thank You!

Comment: What are the symptoms of the problem you observe? Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: I will check the console

Comment: There was a module import error that I fixed, but now there is an error saying that the resource was not found, although in my code editor when I follow the links everything is fine.

Comment: What specific resource was not found? Edit your question to include the full text of the errors you see.

Comment: Actually, I think that the error that happens after the module error is because of the CORS policy, so I am going to install an HTTP server and get the game working from there.  Then, when I put it on a website hosting service, there will be no problem.

Comment: If that solves your problem, be sure to post it as an Answer to help future devs who run into this situation.  Also, don't forget to include the CORS error message in your question so it's more searchable.